# Ionic 2 List not updated with data

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io, ionic2

I am trying to use Socket.io with Ionic 2. I am trying to show the received data in a list, bound to an array. I have the following code.

```
this.socket.on('Message', function(data){
  console.log("Received: " + data);
  this.messages.push(data);
})
```

And the html looks like,

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages">
      {{ msg }}
    </ion-item>  
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Although I can see the array being updated in the browser's console, the list is not reflecting any changes. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrow functions `() =>`, otherwise `this.` won't point to your current class instance.

```
this.socket.on('Message', (data) => {
  console.log("Received: " + data);
  this.messages.push(data);
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Still getting used to these new functions.